# Possible ways to migrate data from MS Access to SQL Server 2008 Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007

I have database in MS Access in which new table is generated to store the records of each day. I want to transfer the data from the current day table to SQL Server Table.

In SQL server I have only one table and Data will append everyday.

What are the possible ways to achieve this functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do this.The one is Import Export Wizard which is listed below:

1) Using Import-Export wizard: This will do is get the data from source (for you will be Access) and put it in Destination database ( which will be SQL Server)

You can call this package through SQL Agent ( you can make it run every day, weekly, monthly)

[Import and Export wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx)

http://www.packtpub.com/article/transferring-data-ms-access-2003-to-sql-server-2008

Comment: I am using SQL Server express. It doesn't have SQL Agent.

Answer (score 0):

I would explore creating a [Linked Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to Access, and create a stored procedure to load the data, which you could schedule with the Windows Task Scheduler and [sqlcmd](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Taken from MSDN post

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/015d8295-a57a-4dc9-b3e2-6da1cfe8ab6d/convert-an-access-db-to-sqlexpress

Access has a tool called the Upsize Wizard built directly into the product to help you do this. A second alternative is the SQL Server Migration Assistant for Access, which you can learn about here http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh313039.aspx.

Download link below

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=28763